# SCP not working in EC2 (AWS)

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, file-transfer, scp

I can SSH into the EC2 instance:

```
ssh -i "my_key.pem" ec2-user@my-public-ip
```

However, scp doesn't work:

```
scp -r –i "my_key.pem" ./my_file ec2-user@my-public-ip:/home/ec2-user/my_file
```

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   lost connection

I've also tried using public instance DNS, but nothing changes.

Any idea why is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Place `-r` after `-i "my_key.pem"`

Comment: Post the verbose logs of both commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way for this to happen is the private key `mykey.pem` is not found in the current directory. It is possible you tried `ssh` from a directory different than `scp`.

Try the following with full path to your key:

```
scp -r –i /path/to/my_key.pem ./my_file ec2-user@my-public-ip:/home/ec2-user/my_file
```

If it fails, post the output with `-v` option. It will tell you exactly where the problem is

```
scp -v -r –i /path/to/my_key.pem ./my_file ec2-user@my-public-ip:/home/ec2-user/my_file
```

Comment: It turns out that placing scp options in different order than the one stated by @helloV won't make it work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I am bit late but this might be help full to someone.
Do not use the /home/ec2-user. Rather directly use the file name or folder name
E.g. the following command will put your my_file at the home folder (i.e. /home/ec2-user)

```
scp -r –i "my_key.pem" ./my_file ec2-user@my-public-ip:my_file
```

Or Say if you have a folder at /home/ect-user/my_data
Then use the following command to copy your file to the folder

```
scp -r –i "my_key.pem" ./my_file ec2-user@my-public-ip:my_data
```

Answer (score 0):

*Stupidly late addendum*:

To avoid specifying the private key every time, just add to the `.ssh/config` file (create it if not already there) the following (without comments):

```
Host testserver                  // a memorable alias
Hostname 12.34.56.67             // your server ip
User ec2-user                    // user to connect
IdentityFile /path/to/key.pem    // path to the private key
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Then a simple `ssh testserver` should work from anywhere (and consequently your scp too).

I use it to connect with Vim via scp using:

`vim scp://testserver/relative/file/path`

or

`vim scp://testserver//absolute/file/path`

and

`vim scp://testserver/relative/dir/path/` (note the trailing slash)

to respectively edit files and browse folders directly from local (thus using my precious .vimrc *<3* configuration).

Solution found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/427299/vim-scp-parameter-with-private-public-key-pair?newreg=fc2b19cdc130416c802b8b2ba96c2b40)

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue today and found solution for me (not elegant but one which worked). - this solution is good if you want to download something once and rollback all settings afterwards.

**Solution**:
When I specified -v option while using scp I noticed the certificate is being denied for some reason so I went to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set PasswordAuthentication **yes**. Then I used `systemctl restart sshd`.

After this procedure I went to my local machine and used:

```
scp -v -r myname@VPC:/home/{user}/filename.txt path/on/local/machine
```

provided PWD and file transmission has been successful.

Hope this helps to someone :)